# Where to find a circular robot, diameter < 45cm, load bearing >= 30Kg with ROS (1 or 2) installed?

Tags: ros, ros2, mobile-robot, lidar, rgbd

I am looking for a robot with the following specifications:

- Circular, holonomic robot
- Diameter <= 45 cm (17.7 in)
- Load bearing >= 30 Kg (66 lbs)
- ROS enabled + camera & lidar sensor (included or as an option)

I cannot find anything like that anywhere, and I have checked multiple robotics companies. Do you have any suggestions ?

Thank you in advance for your help !

Answer (score 1):

That is a very small footprint for such a high payload - I'm not aware of anything commercially available with those specifications.

For reference, the Freight-100 from Fetch Robotics (now Zebra) is 22" diameter, non-holonomic and has ~100kg payload. That size/payload is basically the low end of commercial platforms. The more hobbyist/education oriented robots can be smaller - but have relatively low payloads (and are rarely holonomic since that adds significant cost).

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the [TIAGo Base](https://pal-robotics.com/robots/tiago-base/). As far as I know, it only supports ROS1. We have it with the Melodic version, but there is also the option for Noetic, so I assume now they come with that upgrade. Its diameter is 540mm, max payload is 100kg. Also comes with proximity sensors and a built-in navigation stack, which can also be accessed.

Edit:
Sorry, I didn't notice that it needs to be smaller than 45cm, but maybe this still helps someone.